# Do I need to add (float) for each variable?

Tags: c

Learning about typecasting in C, and I'm wondering if I need to only have the (float) in front of the price of pumpkins, or in front of price of pumpkins, sales, and days worked like the guy in the tutorial I'm watching.

```
float avg_profit;
int price_of_pumpkin = 10;
int sales = 59;
int days_worked = 7;

avg_profit = (float)price_of_pumpkin * sales / days_worked;

printf("Average daily profit: $%.2f", avg_profit);
```

Comment: Aside: Why are you considering `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: In context, the price should probably be a floating point (`double` or `float`) quantity.  That would be sufficient.  Assuming you don't sell partial pumpkins (half a pumpkin), then quantity (`sales`) make sense as an integer.  If you only count whole days, then `days_worked` can stay an integer, but if you might work half days, maybe that should be a floating point value too.

Answer (score 3):

You only need to cast the first variable in your formula. Once you cast `price_of_pumpkin` to `float`, the result of multiplication becomes float as well, and float division will than be performed.

If it is suggested in the tutorial to cast each variable in the formula, you'd better watch other tutorial, or, even better, read a book.

Comment: It's not a horrible thing to recommend casting everything explicitly. It saves you from having to memorize all the precedence and associativity rules.

Comment: That's not true though. Suppose the formula is `x + y / 3`. Perhaps the best rule would be to have the variables of the proper type from the beginning ;-)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala if you mean that it might not be true in general case, I agree. Corrected my statement to be more clear.

Comment: @Barmar I believe, knowing the rule is better than cargo-culting casting, which makes code verbose and hard to read. But it's just me.

Comment: I don't consider this cargo-culting, just being explicit and careful. Similarly, I regularly recommend adding extra parentheses to make your intended grouping clear, since there are many cases where the default precedence is not intuitive. Even if the programmer knows the rules, it makes it easier for readers.

Comment: And does adding a .0 at the end of a number convert it to a float automatically? Say if you were to divide an integer by 3, but you need the answer to be a float?

Answer (score 2):

For operators `*` and `/`, if one of the operands is `float`, then any other operand of integral type will be converted to `float` before the operation is performed, and the result again is `float`.

If you have a chain of such operators, then you have to take associativity into account. The associativity for mathematical operators like `+`, `-`, `*`, and `/` is left-to-right.

So - to answer your question - it is sufficient to cast the very first operand to `float`; Other operands will get converted implicitly, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> if I need to only have the (float) in front of the price of pumpkins

In C, many operators such as `*,/,+,-` (not all) require the operands, after the usual promotions, to be the same type.

When they differ, one of them is converted into the type of the other.

In the cases of `int math_operator float`, `float math_operator int`, the `int` is converted to a `float`.

---

Let us try differ ways.

```
int price_of_pumpkin = 10;
int sales = 59;
int days_worked = 7;
```

Will `avg_profit1` print as `"84.29"` or `"84.00"`?

```
float avg_profit1 = price_of_pumpkin * sales / days_worked;
```

> `float = int * int / int` does the math with `int` arithmetic first and then converts to `float`.
>  `84.00`

Will `avg_profit2` print as `"84.29"` or `"84.00"`?

```
float avg_profit2 = (float)price_of_pumpkin * sales / days_worked;
```

> `float = float * int / int` does all the math with `float` arithmetic first and then assigns.
>  `84.29`

Will `avg_profit3` print as `"84.29"` or `"84.00"`?

```
float avg_profit3 = (float)price_of_pumpkin * (float)sales / days_worked;
```

> `float = float * float / int` does all the math with `float` arithmetic first and then assigns.
>  `84.29`
>  "Do I need to add (float) for each variable?" --> No. Casting more objects to `float` did not change things in this case.

---

Advanced detail.

Even `float * float / float` may be done using `double` or `long double` math as C allows, depending on the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`, the use of higher precision math.